# Remove duplicate elements from a drop down list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is the dropdown list box. I want to remove the duplicate "Apple" using javascript.

```
<select id="Fruits">
<option value="Apple" >Apple</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Mango">Mango</option>
<option value="Apple" >Apple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [].slice.call(Fruits.options).map(function(a){if(this[a.value]){ Fruits.removeChild(a); }else{this[a.value]=1;}  },{})

Comment: @dandavis ... why didn't you just put that as an answer..?

Comment: @Shawn31313  the downvote scared me away...

Comment: @dandavis is that plain JavaScript or using a JavaScript library?

Comment: JSTL runs on the server side. Not sure how you plan to use it here since you're not even setting anything from Java server side t your `<select>`.

Comment: plain ole js. well, modern js instead of "ole", but plain to be certain...

Comment: @dandavis then you're losing rep!

Comment: @dandavis post it as an answer.

Comment: @dandavis - added your method as an answer, with some formatting and variations.

Answer (score 3):

This is @DanDavis answer for reference, I'm adding it as, you know, public service. Plus a bit of formatting and a couple of alternatives to cover similar use cases.

```
var fruits = document.getElementById("Fruits");

[].slice.call(fruits.options)
  .map(function(a){
    if(this[a.value]){ 
      fruits.removeChild(a); 
    } else { 
      this[a.value]=1; 
    } 
  },{});
```

If you are working with a select populated by a database (a pretty obvious use case) and the values are `ids` and the `innerText` is the duplicates you want to remove. Then instead you'd want:

```
[].slice.call(fruits.options)
  .map(function(a){
    if(this[a.innerText]){ 
      fruits.removeChild(a); 
    } else { 
      this[a.innerText]=1; 
    } 
  },{});
```

Furthermore, if you want to retain the selected option (it might not be the first occurrence matched.) Try this:

```
[].slice.call(fruits.options)
  .map(function(a){
    if(this[a.innerText]){ 
      if(!a.selected) fruits.removeChild(a); 
    } else { 
      this[a.innerText]=1; 
    } 
  },{});
```

Comment: I know this is old however, I wanted to know if there was a way to map ID's and check for each of them?

Comment: @Especially if you post this as a question, I will answer it. (You may find a similar question already exists.)  Seems like you just need an array of the ID's as strings and the map those, and return the element found, or null.  You could optionally compact the array (with lo-dash/underscore etc.) - if you post a question, link it here.

Comment: I've posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562969/remove-multiple-duplicate-options-from-drop-down-list I tried mocking up something but I'm terrible at javascript. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In ES3 POJS you could do this.

Javascript

```
function removeDuplicateOptions(selectNode) {
    if (typeof selectNode === "string") {
        selectNode = document.getElementById(selectNode);
    }

    var seen = {},
        options = [].slice.call(selectNode.options),
        length = options.length,
        previous,
        option,
        value,
        text,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
        option = options[i];
        value = option.value,
        text = option.firstChild.nodeValue;
        previous = seen[value];
        if (typeof previous === "string" && text === previous) {
            selectNode.removeChild(option);
        } else {
            seen[value] = text;
        }
    }
}

removeDuplicateOptions("Fruits");
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/eAVxm/)</kbd>