# Remove Multiple Duplicate Options From Drop-down List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708014/remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-drop-down-list-using-javascript) I'd like to find out how to remove duplicate options from drop down lists, however I'd like to map a list of ID's to search from and see if they have duplicate options to splice out as opposed to just one input selector.

An example of this would be as follows:

```
<select id="MeatList">
<option value="OBgYN7" >Ham</option>
<option value="ELmn5">Beef</option>
<option value="KrUKt6">Chicken</option>
<option value="OBgYN7" selected="selected">Ham</option>
</select>

<select id="Seats">
<option value="2" >Table For Two</option>
<option value="3">Table For Three</option>
<option value="5">Table for Five</option>
<option value="10" >Party Table</option>
</select>

<select id="Lastname">
<option value="Tao" >The Tao's</option>
<option value="Smith">The Smith's</option>
<option value="Samuels">The Samuels'</option>
<option value="Smith" >The Smith's</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, the inputs MeatList and Lastname have duplicate values, I want to be able to search all drop down boxes for duplicate values (or inner text) and splice them out. Would that be possible through mapping of some sort?

**The code to be used would be:**

```
[].slice.call(fruits.options)
  .map(function(a){
    if(this[a.innerText]){ 
      if(!a.selected) fruits.removeChild(a); 
    } else { 
      this[a.innerText]=1; 
    } 
  },{});
```

And to get an idea of what I mean by mapping the drop-down lists, I would use a code like this:

```
 var idlist= ["MeatList", "Seats", "Lastname"];
     var handlelists = idlist.join("|");
    [].slice.call(handlelists.options)
      .map(function(a){
        if(this.search([a.innerText])){ 
          if(!a.selected) handlelists.removeChild(a); 
        } else { 
          this[a.innerText]=1; 
        } 
      },{});
```

Comment: Is the select generated by a server-side script? If yes, consider do the work there

Comment: Do you want to de-dupe each list on it's own, or de-dupe the combined list of options? Also can we assume both value and text will be duplicate (ie. only text the Values?)

Comment: @EmacsFodder Each list on its own; and yes it's fair to assume the text is the same as the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you thought was going on in the `handleLists` part of your script. You just need to wrap the other segment in an iterator (`forEach`) after finding the elements corresponding to the IDs.

```
var idList= ["MeatList", "Seats", "Lastname"].map(function(id){return document.getElementById(id)});

idList.forEach(function(select){
  [].slice.call(select.options)
  .map(function(a){
    if(this[a.value]){
      select.removeChild(a); 
    } else {
      this[a.value]=1; 
    }
  },{});
});
```

Of course, this is bad.  You should make de-duplicating a function of it's own, eg.:

```
function deDuplicate(select){
  [].slice.call(select.options)
    .map(function(a){
      if(this[a.value]){
        select.removeChild(a); 
      } else {
        this[a.value]=1; 
      }
    },{});
}
```

and then:

```
var idList= ["MeatList", "Seats", "Lastname"].map(function(id){return document.getElementById(id)});    
idList.forEach(function(select){ deDuplicate(select); });
```

Personally I recommend learning/using CoffeeScript as it *uncrufts* Javascript a great deal, the de-dupe looks like this:

```
deDuplicate = (select)->
  [].slice.call(select.options).map (a)->
    if @[a.value] 
      select.removeChild a
    else 
      @[a.value] = 1
  , {}
```

and then wrapped you can do:

```
deDuplicate select for select in ["MeatList", "Seats", "Lastname"].map (id)-> 
  document.getElementById id
```

Which reads more plainly as english, at least to me it does. As always YMMV.

Comment: The CoffeeScript definitely looks much cleaner I'll definitely try reading up on it. Thank you

Comment: Also, how would one target a child within select option group? It's not specifically a child of the selector.

Comment: @Especially do you mean an `<optgroup>` collection?

Comment: @Especially the easiest thing to do would be to give each option group an id of it's own (if possible.) and then simply target them using the id list technique as shown in the answer, naming the deDuplicate parameter to group or parent would make it read better (ie. for when you come back and want to understand WTH is going on.)