# Remove Duplicates from Dropdown List By javascript only

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a select dropdown field that is being created dynamically from a database . Due to the way this is being created it results in the dropdown having duplicate items and values.

```
<select id="locationList">
<option value="1">Andover</option>
<option value="2">Bishops waltham</option>
<option value="1">Andover</option>
<option value="3">Boscombe</option>
<option value="4">Bournemouth</option>
<option value="2">Bishops waltham</option>
<option value="4">Bournemouth</option>

</select>
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to use some code on the page which checks the dropdown for duplicates and removes duplicates from the menu only by Javascript No Jquery?

Thanks in advance,

Abhinav

Comment: How are you creating that list?

Comment: Why don't you get get items uniquely from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has `removeChild` option, you can use it to remove duplicate value:

```js
var fruits = document.getElementById("locationList");

[].slice.call(fruits.options)
  .map(function(a){
    if(this[a.value]){ 
      fruits.removeChild(a); 
    } else { 
      this[a.value]=1; 
    } 
  },{});
```

```html
<select id="locationList">
<option value="1">Andover</option>
<option value="2">Bishops waltham</option>
<option value="1">Andover</option>
<option value="3">Boscombe</option>
<option value="4">Bournemouth</option>
<option value="2">Bishops waltham</option>
<option value="4">Bournemouth</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708014/remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-drop-down-list-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the set as suggested here: [alternatives](https://gist.github.com/telekosmos/3b62a31a5c43f40849bb) or [another alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/7750124).

`[ ...new Set([ ...<arg1>, ...<arg2> ]) ]` for e.g.

`var y = [ ...new Set([ ...[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ...[3, 4, 5] ]) ]`

`// expected output: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`

Use the output to bind to the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

**Do it with dual for loop using pure js**

Simple and easy way with **select remove** method

```js
function clearList() {
  var x = document.getElementById("locationList");
  //count the lenth of select optons
  var listLength = x.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < listLength; j++) {
      //i != j This prevents the actual index from being deleted
      //x.options[i].value == x.options[j].value => it finds the duplicate index.
      if (x.options[i].value == x.options[j].value && i != j) {
        //Remove duplicate option element
        x.remove(j);
        //Refresh the list Length
        listLength--;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="locationList">
  <option value="1">Andover</option>
  <option value="2">Bishops waltham</option>
  <option value="1">Andover</option>
  <option value="3">Boscombe</option>
  <option value="4">Bournemouth</option>
  <option value="2">Bishops waltham</option>
  <option value="4">Bournemouth</option>
</select>

<p>Click to remove duplicates</p>
<button onclick="clearList()">Remove</button>
```